# Set static hostname/ip mapping for one command

Tags: dns

Is there a way to add a local hostname/ip mapping on the fly on the commandline? (Thus, editing `/etc/hosts` would not be a good solution in this case )

Something in the vain of:

```
HOSTS=127.0.0.2=localsignificanthostname;127.0.0.3=otherspecialhostname ping localsignificanthostname
```

Comment: I wonder, why you do not ping the IP address instead.

Comment: ping might be a stupid example in hindsight. For applications which do HTTP requests, the hostname is of vital importance. Curl for example does have a separate host option which you can pass along such that curl knowns which host header to send, not all applications have this.

Comment: OK, I see. The closest thing I found is this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483167/use-reference-to-file-instead-of-ip-in-etc-hosts

Comment: nope. just add them to /etc/hosts. or run a local name server.  or rely on the crappy and unreliable avahi daemon.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the OS, but  in Linux you can use `unshare(1)`:

```
# unshare -m sh -c "mount -B /tmp/fakehosts /etc/hosts; ping localsignificanthostname"
```

requires root, namespaces and reasonably recentish kernel (which you usually have).